# Why doesn't my jQuery Mobile code work?

Tags: jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm not sure how to make any jQuery mobile event like tap or touchstart work on my mobile device. When I run it on desktop, it all works fine. Using PhoneGap to build the apk.

The code should be working on mobile according to the jQuery mobile docs. Tried to debug it on mobile as well, doesn't seem the jquery even loads...

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

body {
  background-color: red;
}

h1 {
  position: absolute;
  right: 30px;
  padding: 30px;
  color: white;
  text-shadow: none;
}

#hello {
  z-index: 3;
  background-color: #222222;
}

#hello > div {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: green;
}

.ui-page { background:transparent; }

.ui-input-text {
  border: none;
}


<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src * 'unsafe-inline'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/jquery-3.2.1.min.js">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
   </script>

    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="app" data-role='page'>
        <h1>PhoneGap</h1>
        <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
            <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
            <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
        </div>
    </div>



    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        app.initialize();
    </script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('h1').bind("tap", function() {
          $(this).css({color: 'red'});

        });
      });

      /* works
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('h1').on("click", function() {
          $(this).css({color: 'red'});

        });
      });
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Twice included library..

Comment: @pedram Doesn't work even with removing the jquery <link>

Comment: No, it's just  a notice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Cordova or in PhoneGap applications use jQuery that you will have in `www` directory of app that you are publishing, and then include it like this for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and not from cdn, or remote address like: `https://code.jquery.com`

Comment: Zamijenio sam CDN, ali i dalje radi samo jQuery. jQuery mobile uopce ne radi. Mozes li molim te pogledat sta je greska, update-o sam code gore.

Comment: Radim app, u tom i je problem. Trebaju mi touch events

Comment: ej,, pa ne treba ti jQuery Mobile da bi koristio touch evente. Sve evente poput, `touchstart`, `touchmove` itd mozes normlano sa obicnim jQueryem koristiti, tako da smao makni jQuery mobile i neka ostane jQuery u source-u

Comment: Nemogu vjerovat da je to bio problem. Da jQuery Mobile uopce nije bio potreban. Znaci 3 dana se vec patim, sve zivo sam probo... Uskoro moram app napravit za jednu firmu, a dosad sam samo website-ove pravio. Nikad nisam radio striktno na app projektu. Doslovno si mi spasio zivot :D Hvala ti!!